# Correct notation for compound conditions of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Let $X$ be a discrete random variable, and $P(X = x)$ is its probability mass function of a binomial experiment.

If I want the probability of obtaining between 5 and 10 successes, I write $P(4<X<11)$.

However, what if I want *either* between 5 and 10 *or* between 15 and 20?

I could think of:

$P(4<X<11\vee14<X<21)$

$P(4<X<11\cup14<X<21)$

$P(X=x:4<x<11\vee14<x<21)$

How would one write it and is the use of logical operators acceptable since, in probability experiments, one uses set notation most of the time?

Comment: What is the number of trials ?

Comment: Does it matter? Let's say $n=30$.

Comment: I thought about using the converse probability. But after reading your question more carefully I think it doesn´t help. In general I prefer your second expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In probability one usually works with events. In essence the probability operator $P$ is defined for sets, i.e. in your case we have the set $A = \{ 4 < X < 11\}$ and the set $B = \{ 14 < X< 21\}$. How the probability operator works is it takes in a set for example
$$P( 4 < X < 11 ) = P(A) = P( \{ 4 < X < 11\}),$$
which is all notationally the same. Now using set theory a combination (either) of both events is the union, namely $C :=A \cup B = \{ 4 < X < 11 \} \cup \{ 14 < X < 21\}$. This new set $C$ is precisely the event when A or B happens. Hence in correct notation we have
$$ P(C) = P\left(\{ 4 < X < 11 \} \cup \{ 14 < X < 21\}\right). $$
In probability theory one does not use logical operators but only events, in some more basic books it may be $\bf{defined}$ that indeed
$$P\left(\{ 4 < X < 11 \} \cup \{ 14 < X < 21\}\right) = P( (4 < X < 11) \lor (14 < X < 21)). $$
Or some variation of the above but this is not typical notation. Notice that I used $\lor$ as this is the logical operator for or.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! You say you used $\lor$, but you did use $\land$?

Comment: indeed, that was a mistake!